# React-select-checkboxes onClose event not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an react app where I am using `react-multiselect-checkboxes` library to display multiple checkboxes inside an dropdown.
This is I have done so far.

```
<ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes
        placeholderButtonLabel = {jarNames.value}
        options={this.props.dropDownOptions}
        onChange = {(selectedDependency) => this.props.selectingDependencies(selectedDependency)}
        onClose = {this.doSomething} />
```

But when I close the dropdown this `onClose` event doesn't gets fired up. Same thing is happening with `onOpen` event.

```
doSomething = () => {
    console.log('yo man');
}
```

`Package.json` versions : `react-multiselect-checkboxes: "^0.1.1`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: it would be easier, if you sandbox your code.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `doSomething` function

Comment: it is simply a log statement. I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not calling correct prop.

The prop name is `onMenuClose` instead of `onClose`.

```
<ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes
          onMenuClose={this.doSomething}
          options={options} />
```

You can refer to [react-select prop](https://react-select.com/props)

Working code:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes from 'react-multiselect-checkboxes';

class App extends React.Component {
  doSomething = () => {
    console.log('something')
  }
  render () {
    const options = [
      { label: 'Thing 1', value: 1},
      { label: 'Thing 2', value: 2},
    ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ReactMultiSelectCheckboxes
          onMenuClose={this.doSomething}
          options={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: is there a prop which is fired when we open the dropbox. I have tried both onOpen and onMenuOpen but this does'nt seems to work.